# Error when implementing gravity within movement script (cannot convert float to vector3)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement gravity in a movement test for a first-person project I'm working on.
Here's the error code:

```
public void ProcessMove(Vector2 input)
    {
        Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
        moveDirection.x = input.x;
        moveDirection.z = input.y;
        controller.Move(transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        float playerVelocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        if(isGrounded && playerVelocity.y > 0){
            playerVelocity.y = -2f;
        }   
        controller.Move(playerVelocity.y * Time.deltaTime);
    }    
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

> Assets\Scripts\PlayerMotor.cs(34,25): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: tried it, still doesn't work.

Comment: Don't forget to _accept_ and _upvote_ my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems in your code.

The statement:

```
float playerVelocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
```

...should read:

```
playerVelocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
```

and the statement:

```
controller.Move(playerVelocity.y * Time.deltaTime);
```

...should read:

```
controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
```

Consider combining your `controller.Move` into a single statement.  You can do this by having multiple vector operations and using the final result in `controller.Move`